# What's the meaning of: “Gotcha. Well a task it is...” by HM?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, slang

What's the meaning of the Human Resource's response?

I emailed him first:

> What I sent to you were websites that I developed for a web competition. Do you mean actual company's website? I did have two months' intern in a web company, but I just created flash advertisements and posted them to the webpages. I have not yet join beneficial projects. 
>   Or if you want, you can give me a task of developing webpages...

He replied：

> Gotcha. Well a task it is and it will pertain to this project.

What did he mean?

Comment: You better ask him. How are we supposed to know what he thought when he wrote the sentence?

Comment: As the others have said, it's hard to know what the person meant, but here's my guess: "Gotcha." (slang pronunciation of "Got you") → "I understand." / "a task it is" → "the work product that you have submitted is acceptable evidence of work experience" / "it will pertain to this project" → "it is relevant to the project that you are trying to join, and will be considered as part of your qualification for that job."  But, yeah, just my guess.  It would help to know the preceding usages of the words "task" and "project".

Comment: What he meant was - OK, whatever you just wrote will be considered a task in your resume, and that is considered relevant to the project for which they wish to consider you.

Comment: I don't like seeing questions where they don't bother or make effort to provide more info - making us guess what the context is.

Comment: Apparently I read this differently.  “A task it is.” means, “OK, I’ll give you task.” While we don’t know what project is being discussed it’s seems clear it’s the project they are working on and to which Chen Lu is applying.  “*A <noun> it is*” is a phrase used to announce that a decision has been made and what that decision is-  Should we have fish or chicken?  How many want fish? 5 of you... And chicken?  Only 2.  Ok Fish it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the plain reading: HR is responding to elements of your original email. There are 3 parts to their answer: "Gotcha", "A task it is" and "it will pertain to this project". I'll note the relevant quotes from your original email in *italics*.

**Gotcha**

Your opening statement was *What I sent to you were websites that I developed for a web competition*.

HR's response is a colloquial term for "I got you", or expanded further, "I've got (understood the meaning of) what you are trying to say".

**A task it is**

HR agrees to (one option in) your request: *Or if you want, you can give me a task of developing webpages*.

**It will pertain to this project**

The statement is just giving you more detail about the "task" mentioned in the first part of their sentence. This links up with your request for clarification: *Do you mean actual company's website?* as your email indicated some confusion on a related topic previously.

Comment: great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

He is probably saying that he is giving you a task (which you asked for) and that the task is related to the project you are applying to.

Comment: We don't encourage an answer that contains *probably*. We don't welcome a question which is just for interpretation without enough context. We can never know what he is referring to with "this project". Can you?